# SwingUtilities invokeLater GUI update with JList

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, swingutilities

Good day,

I've read a few other stack overflow postings and other tutorials, but I can't get my GUI to update correctly after a button starts a long process. I've attached the full code of the problem that I am having. Notice if you run the code, the JList gets updated all at once at the end instead of every iteration of the for loop.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class theframe extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JList list;
    private DefaultListModel listmodel;
    private JButton start;

    public theframe()
    {
        listmodel = new DefaultListModel();
        list = new JList(listmodel);
        start = new JButton("Start");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);

        list.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));

        start.addActionListener(this);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(start);
        p.add(list);

        this.add(p);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        theframe frame = new theframe();

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        if(arg0.getSource() == start)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {   
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        // the JList should update one by one
                        listmodel.addElement("Start pushed ");
                    }
                });



                try
                {
                                    //This thread sleep simulates a long job
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is the fact that you are calling the `invokeLater` method already from the EDT (*Event Dispatching Thread*).

The method `actionPerformed` is called from the EDT so what happens is that the `sleep` call just stops the EDT itself: you can imagine that this is not how it should work, no EDT running means no GUI updates.

Since it's a time consuming task you should implement it in a `Thread`/`Runnable` so that you can execute it in parallel and then call the `invokeLater` from this other thread.

Something like:

```
class LongProcess extends Thread {
  public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...);
      Thread.sleep(300);
    }
  }
}

void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
  LongProcess process = new LongProcess();
  process.start();
}
```

Comment: Jack beat me to the answer while I was typing it. So I'll just +1 his because it's exactly what I would say :) Just a side note to add that `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` should be used in threads to update Swing/AWT components.

Comment: Thank you @Jack and george_h! Much appreciated! I didn't understand that the actionPerformed came from the EDT, but I guess it makes sense now. Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 4):

The `actionPerformed` method will be called on the Event Dispatch Thread. Calling `Thread.sleep` on the EDT stops it from updating your GUI. Since your GUI cannot update, your `JList` will not repaint itself when items are added to it until after your loop exits.

You should probably be using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html). ([`SwingWorker` tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html))